# Proving $G\cong \Bbb{Z}_p$ if $|G|$ is prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, proof-verification

For a group $G$, if $|G|$ is prime, then I have to prove $G\cong \Bbb{Z}_p$.

Take any element $g\in G$. As $G$ cannot have proper subgroups, and as it also has finite order, $|g|=p$. Hence, $G=\{1,g,g^2,\dots,g^{p-1}\}$. We know $\Bbb{Z}_p=\{0,1,2,\dots,p-1\}$. Hence, $f:G\to\Bbb{Z}_p$ defined by $f(g^r)=r$ for any $r\in\Bbb{Z}_p$ is a homomorphism.

If we can now prove that the kernel of this mapping is $\{1\}$, then we're done. Clearly, $1$ is the only element that maps to $0$ in the above homomorphism.

1. Is the above reasoning correct?
2. What are some other ways of proving isomorphism between the two groups? Is proving that the kernel is composed of only one element the only way? I read somewhere that if provided you have proven $f$ is a homomorphism, and that $h$ is another mapping from $\Bbb{Z}_p$ to $G$, then proving $fg$ is injective and $gf$ is surjective is sufficient to prove isomorphism. But what are the properties of $g$?

Comment: Note that $\{1\}$ is a proper subgroup of $G$.

Comment: In your proof: You should choose $g$ such that $g \neq 1$ or else the order of $g$ will not be $p$, but $1$.

Comment: Yes. I suppose the kernel is always a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: 1) The reasoning is correct to me. 2) You can also show that there exists a homomorphism g, such that gf = id_G, fg= id, then f will be an isomorphism. It's true in any category: if f is a morphism, g is a morphism, fg = id, gf=id, then f is an isomorphism (in that category). Here morphism is a map, which can be a continuous map, homomorphism between groups, modules,...depend on the category.

Comment: If you write "$G$ cannot have proper, nontrivial subgroups", and specify that $g\neq 1$, I think you're set.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld- lol I got what you said just now. Non trivial subgroups it is then.

Comment: examples: 1) f,g are 2 maps between sets, fg= id, gf=id then f is an isomorphism between 2 sets. 2) f,g are group homomorphisms, fg = id, gf=id, then f is an isomorphism between groups. 3) f,g are continuous maps between topological spaces, fg=id, gf=id then f is a homeomorphism(an isomorphism of topological spaces)

Comment: You can also do this by proving that all groups with prime orders are cyclic, then proving that all finite cyclic groups are isomorphic to $Z_n$ where $n$ is the order of the group.

Comment: @JSchlather The overlying question is the same, but this question is a "check my proof" question, so cannot possibly be a duplicate!

Answer (score 1):

As to your point 2, your question *screams* for an application of the [first isomorphism theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem).

Define 
$$
f : \mathbb{Z} \to G, \qquad n \mapsto g^n,
$$
where $1 \ne g \in G$. Because of the rule $g^{n+m} = g^{n} g^{m}$, this is a group homomorphism.

Since $G$ has no proper, nontrivial subgroups, and the image of $f$ contains $g \ne 1$, it follows that $f$ is surjective, and thus
$$
\mathbb{Z} / \ker(f) \cong G,
$$
so that $p = \lvert G \rvert = \lvert \mathbb{Z} : \ker(f) \rvert$.

Thus $\ker(f)$ is the unique subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ of index $p$, that is, $\ker(f) = p \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $|G|=p$, a prime.
Then $|G| > 1$, so there is a non-identity element.
Let $a$ be a non identity element of $G$.

Consider the subgroup generated by $a$:  $\langle a\rangle$

Since $a$ is not $1$,  $a^0 = 1$ and $a^1$ are two distinct elements of $\langle a\rangle$

Thus $|\langle a\rangle |> 1$ ... call this fact (*).

Now by Lagrange's theorem, $|\langle a\rangle|$ must divide $|G|=p$, a prime

The only positive integers that divide prime $p$, are $1$ and $p$
By fact (*), $|\langle a\rangle|$ cannot be $1$, so we must have $|\langle a\rangle| = p$.

Now all cyclic groups of order $p$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$, so you are done.
If you cannot use this fact, then exhibit an isomorphism $f: \langle a\rangle \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p$ by

$f(a^n) = n$

Proof that it is a homomorphism:
$f(a^m \cdot a^n) = f(a^{(m+n)} ) = m + n = f(a^m) + f(a^n)$

Proof that it is an isomorphism (that is, prove $f$ is bijective):
Let's exhibit an inverse of $f$, say $g$:
$g(n) = a^n$

proof it is an inverse:
$f(g(n)) = f(a^n) = n$ , and this is true for all $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$
$g(f(a^n)) = g(n) = a^n$, and this is true for all $a^n$ in $\langle a\rangle$

Thus $f$ is an isomorphism from $\langle a\rangle = |G|$ onto $\mathbb{Z}_p$.